# Neo4j - exclude properties, format JSON

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Let's say I have a Cypher query which matches 10,000 relationships, and I want to put everything in them in the format of a JSON object mapping each record's property "to_node_id" as key, to the node itself as the value - with one or two properties not being included (sanitization).  Is this even possible?

Background: This is for an optimization technique.  Trying to bypass an expensive ORM operation in Rails and formulate the object right in Neo4j, then pass it to the browser, with appropriate items omitted). The goal is to create a lookup table.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
MATCH (from)-[r]-(to)
RETURN {start_node_id: ID(startNode(r)), end_node_id: ID(endNode(r)), prop1: r.prop1} AS r
```

Comment: That is, I wanted all the results as one object.

Comment: Hrmmm, I don't think Cypher is yet very good at building up objects.  You could do `collect` obviously to make it one row...